# Geometric figures inside a bounding box

Tags: volume, geometry

Let us suppose that we have a bounding box of  length $l$, width $w$, and breadth $b$. I wish to know the dimensions / characteristics of a

1. tetrahedron
2. cylinder
3. cube
4. pyramid

inside this bounding box. Where can I get this information?

Comment: Start thinking a little: what if you have a 2d rectangular box ($l$ by $w$), what are the biggest circle, square and triangle you can fit inside?

Comment: Depends how you define the bounding box (alligned with the coordinate system or a free bounding box) and if the figures can be rotated?